# X should have Y to Z (in the past)

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

I was doing some literature homework today, when I became confused as to whether or not the following sentence is grammatical:

> X and Y should have killed Z **to** have prevented Z from killing them.

Should "to" be swapped out for "in order to", or is the whole sentence just plain wrong?

Comment: I think it isn't quite right. _X and Y should have killed Z to  prevent Z from killing them_ would work? Possibly adding a time frame if it isn't clear from context (I mean, to emphasize that Z should have killed X and Y in the past)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence as it stands calls for a simple infinitive, not a perfect infinitive:

> X and Y should have killed Z to prevent Z from killing them.

For a perfect infinitive to be appropriate, it would have to be something on the order of:

> X and Y would have had to have killed Z to have prevented Z from killing them.

Comment: Is "would" required?

Comment: @ChrisIrving  Bill Franke and I are arguing about this ...

Answer (score 0):

It would mean the same thing. *In order to* can usually be reduced to just *to*, and *in order not to* can often be substituted with *to* or *in order to*, followed by an antonym for the subsequent verb.

As for whether the whole thing is "just plain wrong" see other posts regarding verb tenses.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing at all incorrect in the example sentence *X and Y should have killed Z to have prevented Z from killing them.* It simply means that X and Y are now dead because Z killed them. Had they killed Z, he would not have been able to kill them and they would not now be dead. If that's not the case, then the sentence is semantically incorrect but grammatically correct.

I disagree with StoneyB about this, but his substitute sentence is perfectly fine, just one of those unreal conditionals that can also be expressed as "**If X and Y had killed Z** [but they didn't = unreal past condition]**, that would have prevented Z from killing X and Y**". The sentence you ask about is not a conditional but a judgment about what ***should have been done* to prevent the killing of X and Y**.

There's no difference between saying "**You should have listened to my advice not to buy Apple stock to have prevented (your) losing $10,000 overnight**" and "**You would have had to have listened to my advice not to buy Apple stock to have prevented (your) losing $10,000 overnight**".

Comment: This is tricky; but the subordinate perfect infinitive locates its action as anterior to the event in the main clause; and *prevent* is semantically incompatible with that. Shift it forward: *✲ I should kill you, to have prevented you killing me* doesn't work.

Comment: @StoneyB: The original is **should have killed to have prevented**, not **should kill to have prevented**. The sequence of tenses is fine. Am I missing something. Is one of us having a senior moment here? :-)

Comment: I'm forward-shifting to illustrate the syntax. The infinitive is non-tensed. You can only take an action to *prevent* something happening in the future, relative to the action; but *to have prevented* implies something that happened before the action of the main verb, whatever tense that main verb is in.

Comment: @StoneyB: I said in my answer that the OP's sentence means that X & Y are now dead because Z killed them. They should have killed Z to have prevented him from killing them. Too late now, of course. The only thing we're disagreeing on is your analysis of the grammar of the OP's sentence. I think it's fine. You think it's not fine. I'll wait for John Lawler to weigh in on this point.

Comment: @John Lawler apparently did try to edit my post, but I don't know to what effect: the system rejected his edit as too short. Grumble.

Comment: Put it this way: if *to have prevented* means the same thing as *to prevent*, it is unnecessarily verbose; if it means something else, that something else has to be something anterior to *should have killed*.

Comment: @StoneyB: "To have prevented" doesn't mean the same thing as "to prevent" in that sentence, or in any sentence: there's a time problem that has to be considered. That's why we disagree on the grammar of the sentence: in this case, the semantics depend on the tense. Had X & Y wanted to prevent Z from killing them, they would have had to have killed Z (that's the way you put it in your conditional), but they didn't know that, so they didn't kill Z: he killed them. They should have. Had they done it, they would still be alive. You can always send John Lawler a message to ask him about his edit.